# Why does this php script work fine in firefox but not Safari or Opera?

Tags: php, firefox, safari, opera

I have a script that mails me my form data for a classified ad. Yesterday when I left work it worked fine. Now it is only working in FireFox and I'm getting my "else" statement "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify XXXX@XX.COM" in both Opera AND Safari which makes no sense to me.

What's causing this error, and why does it fail in some browsers but work in others?

```
 <script language="javascript">
function submitt()
{
setTimeout('document.paypal.submit()',1000);
}
</script>

<?php 
 $to = "XXX@XXX.com" ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Classified Tests"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Name"} = "Name";  
 $fields{"email"} = "Email"; 
 $fields{"Phone"} = "Phone"; 
 $fields{"Address"} = "Street Address";
 $fields{"City"} = "City";  
 $fields{"State"} = "State"; 
 $fields{"Zip"} = "Zip Code"; 
 $fields{"Classification"} = "Classification"; 
 $fields{"Ad-Headline"} = "Headline"; 
 $fields{"Ad-Content"} = "Ad Content"; 
 $fields{"Words"} = "Word Count"; 
 $fields{"Weeks"} = "Weeks to Run"; 
 $fields{"WordCount"} = "Total Words"; 
 $fields{"Rate"} = "Word Rate"; 
 $fields{"GrossAmountDue"} = "Gross Amount"; 
 $fields{"NonProfit"} = "Non Profit Ad?"; 

$item_name   = $_POST['item_name'];
$amount   = $_POST['amount'] ; 
$currency_code  = $_POST['currency_code'];
$no_shipping = $_POST['item_number'];
$shipping = $_POST['item_number'];
$cmd   = $_POST['cmd'];
$bn  = $_POST['bn'];
$no_note = $_POST['item_number'];
$lc   = $_POST['lc'];
$business   = $_POST['business'];

 $body = "This Ad has been submitted:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

 if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 if($send) 
 {print "Your Ad has been submitted, redirecting to paypal."; echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>submitt();</SCRIPT>";} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify XXX@XXX.com"; } 
 }
}


 ?> 

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal" target="_self" name="paypal" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Classified Ad">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="Amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
</form>
```

What's causing this error, and why does it fail in some browsers but work in others?

Comment: Why the usage of curly braces, when you have square brackets too?

Comment: It *not working* in a certain browser likely has more to do with your input and front-end code, than PHP.

Comment: Yeah, don't use `{}` for arrays. Proper usage is`[]`.

Comment: `"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>submitt();</SCRIPT>"` is probably a typo.

Comment: @arxanas Well I'm using the EXACT same page on both browsers, so it can't be the front end can it? I' new to php lol any suggestions on syntax or anything at all would be great.   Also, the javascript function works fine but if you have a suggestion thatd be great! Although It isn't ever getting to the java script because $send is failing but only in safari which makes no sense to me... I put two T's on purpose.

Comment: @JosiahSouth Having the same page doesn't mean all browsers will use it correctly (see: Internet Explorer). It is almost certainly a front-end code: you should be debugging the output produced by PHP, but probably not the PHP itself.

Comment: I can post the front end page as well if that would help... I'm new so my code may be a bit sloppy, any suggestions or corrections even if not related to the question are appreciated.

Comment: @arxanas that does make sense... I still can't seem to find the problem though. Would you mind taking a look? It'd be a huge amount of code to post here so I think I should just link to it? Or is there a good website for pasting code like this?

Comment: you may try the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check the syntax of your HTML code. The validator will list errors and warnings. Look first at errors, and try to see if one specific error could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I'm just really confused as to why it was working fine yesterday and now it just isn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll work if you send it from your own email address with a `PHP_EOL`.

```
mail("XXX@XXX.com", "subject", "body", "From: Me" . PHP_EOL); // 'From' can be anything
```

See [PHP: `mail` - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try the suggestions in the comments first, then try using this JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit()
{
setTimeout(function(){document.paypal.submit();},1000);
}
</script>
```

I've wrapped the submit code in an anonymous function rather than a string, which is encouraged here: [Efficient JavaScript - Dev.Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#timeouts).

Also, using `<script language=` is **deprecated**, you should use `type` instead (`text/javascript`). See [`script` - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Script).

Comment: Huh... That makes sense, thanks for that because that's of good use for sure. But I've tried removing the javascript entirely as it's only needed for my second form to submit, and it still didn't work. Right now I need to get $send to stop failing before I can move on to the next form submitting. Is there a chat function here?

Comment: @JosiahSouth There is chat. [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com).