# PHP - mail only sending on Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, sendmail

I am having a weird issue where the PHP `mail` function will send e-mails only from Chrome.  Here is the form HTML:

I have checked validation on the HTML, yet I can verify that e-mails can only be received when the user was using Chrome.  Here is the validation code:

```
if (isset($_POST['email_from']) && isset($_POST['contact-name']))
{
    function set_email_recipent($contact_name) {
        $result = "";
        switch ($contact_name) {
            default:
                $result = "info@mysite.com";
                break;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $email_to = set_email_recipent($_POST['contact-name']);
    $email_subject = "Contact Inquiry";


    function died($error)
    {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.";
        echo $error;
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.";
        die();
    }

    // validation-expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email_from']) || !isset($_POST['phone']) || !isset($_POST['comments']))
    {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email_from']; // required
    if (isset($_POST['email_subject'])) {
        $email_subject = "mysite.com Contact Inquiry" . $_POST['email_subject'];
    }
    $telephone = $_POST['phone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $company_name = $_POST['company-name']; //not required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from))
    {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name))
    {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.';
    }
    if (strlen($comments) < 2)
    {
        $error_message .= 'Please type in a message longer than two characters.';
    }
    if (strlen($error_message) > 0)
    {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "There has been an inquiry from a customer at mysite.com.  The user's form details are included below:\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: " . clean_string($email_subject) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Company name: " . clean_string($company_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: " . clean_string($telephone) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: " . clean_string($comments);

// create email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
        ?>
        Your inquiry has been successfully sent.  We will be in touch with you shortly.  Recipent was <?php echo $email_to ?>, message was <?php echo $email_message; ?>, headers were <?php echo $headers;
        }
    else {
        ?> Error!  Please try again...  Recipent was <?php echo $email_to ?>, message was <?php echo $email_message; ?>, headers were <?php echo $headers;
    }
}

else {
    echo "<h1>Error</h1><p>There was an error.</p>";
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id = "contact" action = "validation.php" method = "post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Info</legend>
        <label for = "contact-name">Contact:<em>*</em></label>
        <select name = "contact-name" required = "required" title = "Contact" id = "contact-name" autofocus = "autofocus">
            <option value = "" selected = "">Choose one:</option>
            <optgroup label = "Sales">
                <option value = "justin">Justin - Account Rep</option>
                <option value = "sherri">Sherri - Account Rep</option>
                <option value = "sean">Sean - Account Rep</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label = "Accounting">
                <option value = "shauna">Shauna - Accounts Payable</option>
                <option value = "kristi">Kristi - Accounts Receivable</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label = "Administration">
                <option value = "matt">Matt - Operations Manager</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label = "Art Department">
                <option value = "cassidy">Cassidy - Graphic Designer</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

        <label for = "name">Name:<em>*</em></label>
        <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" title = "Name" required = "required" placeholder = "Your Name">

        <label for = "company-name">Company:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "company-name" id = "company-name" title = "Company" placeholder = "Your company name - ex. My Company Inc.">

        <label for = "email_from">Email:<em>*</em></label>
        <input type = "email" name = "email_from" id = "email_from" title = "Email" required = "required" placeholder = "Your Email - ex. yourname@gmail.com">
        <label for = "phone">Phone:<em>*</em></label>
        <input type = "tel" name = "phone" id = "phone" title = "Phone" required = "required" placeholder = "(403) 555-5555">


        <label for = "email_subject">Subject:<em>*</em></label>
        <input type = "text" name = "email_subject" id = "email_subject" title = "Subject" required = "required" placeholder = "Subject - ex. 555 Main Street, Graffiti, etc.">


        <label for = "comments">Comments:<em>*</em></label>
        <textarea name = "comments" cols = "10" rows = "15" id = "comments" title = "Comments" required = "required" placeholder = "Got anything you want to tell us?  Put it here."></textarea>

    </fieldset>
    <div class = "row form-actions">
        <button class = "btn large" type = "submit" id = "validate">Send <i class = "icon-mail"></i></button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Why is it that this works in Chrome and not other browsers?  How can I fix this?

Comment: mail() couldn't care less what browser a user is using. Its job is to send emails, not change its behavior because someone's using Chrome instead of IE or Firefox. If it's acting differently in different browsers, then it's YOUR code that's causing that difference, not mail itself.

Comment: What is causing you to think that the user must be on Chrome for the script to work? PHP is a server side language.

Comment: Added HTML.  I am well aware that ``mail`` is cross-browser, but I have found others with similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993046/why-does-this-php-script-work-fine-in-firefox-but-not-safari-or-opera

Comment: Just ran some tests in Browserstack: working in IE, FF for Windows, FF Mobile for Android... but not FF on my local machine or Safari... ideas?

Comment: What does your php output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some rigorous testing, we determined that it was the client's mail server that was acting up.  Contacting their technical support and requesting a copy of the mail server logs allowed us to determine that some large number of e-mails were being rejected as spam.

Others experiencing similar problems should consult their client's technical department responsible for managing the corresponding mail servers in order to first determine whether the e-mails are being properly received prior to assuming any issue on the browser side.